# Understanding Recursion(permutations) Python

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

```
def perms(s):
  '''(str) -> list of str
  Return all permutations of s.
  '''
  if s == '':
    return ['']
  smaller = perms(s[1:])
  print(smaller)
  bigger = []
  for p in smaller:
    for i in range(len(p) + 1):
      new_perm = p[:i] + s[0] + p[i:]
      bigger.append(new_perm)
  return bigger

perms('abc')
```

This is my prof's code. I get how the recursion works for this code, but cannot seem to figure out how smaller equals to 'cb'

---

perms('abc')

s[1:] ='bc'

perms('bc')

s[1:]='c'

perms('c')

s[1:]=''

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you call recursively: `smaller = perms(s[1:])` the variable `smaller` gets assigned with whatever is returned from the call `perms(s[1:])`.

When `s = 'bc'` and `i=1` and `p='c'` the expression:

```
new_perm = p[:i] + s[0] + p[i:]
```

is evaluated to `cb`(which on the next line is appended to `bigger` and later on returned back to the recursive call).

Comment: What happens when i=0?

Comment: copy the expression, assign `i = 0` and print the expression - you'll see exactly what it evaluates to. remember that it has different values per different values in `smaller` and per each character in `smaller`!

Comment: "When s = 'bc' and i=1 and p='c'" What happens at i-0, instead of 1, thats what i meant

Comment: You can assign the variables, print it and see that it will assign `'bc'` into `new_perm`